killing a TCl/tk process cleanly in Windows
I'm having to kill a TCL/tk process in the task manager
and I want to do it within the batch file.
Here is the batch file that calls up the TCL/tk process.
START /B sbcl-shen.exe
C:\ActiveTcl\bin\wish.exe "C:\Users\shend\OneDrive\Desktop\Shen\S38.3\StLib\Tk\root.tcl"
This starts a Lisp application Shen/SBCL and allows the TCL/tk event loop in root to
kick in.  Everything seems to be peachy until I kill my application by
exiting Shen and killing the root window.
However a look at the task manager shows there is a TCL process
still running and this has to be killed lest it screw up the next session.
I'm having to kill this process in the task manager.  The question is - is there
a command that can be placed in the batch file to do what I have to do
in the task manager?
Killing the TCl/tk window called root did not end the TCL process
as I hoped.

Killing a process is inherently not clean. Have the program shut down itself gracefully instead.

That said, if the Lisp part calls a TCL process, it could be two processes runnung, and you may need to kill the whole process tree. Refeer to this question for this: Terminate a process of a process tree in command line (Windows).
